# MIDI file byte layout

Tags: midi

Based on [this page](http://www.ccarh.org/courses/253/handout/smf/), I started to learn how a MIDI works, and I downloaded a sample MIDI file to see if I can extract all it's info.

This is the MIDI file:

```
4D 54 68 64 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 03 00 04 4D 54
72 6B 00 00 00 A1 00 C0 69 00 90 3C 5A 01 41 5A ...
```

The first 14 bytes are header information, and I have no problem with these.

The following bytes tell information about the track chunk; the four first ones are `4D 54 72 6B`, which is `Mtrk` in ascii, which is what determines a track chunk; the following 4 bytes determine the number of bytes following that last byte in the same chunk, so `00 00 00 A1` (`161` in decimal) says that there are `161` bytes following it in the same track chunk.

Now it's turn of *track events*

The first byte is `00` which tells that the delta-time is `0`, the next byte tells us it's a midi-event (more precisely, a *program-change* command which selects the program `69` in MIDI channel `0` - from [here](http://www.somascape.org/midi/tech/mfile.html)).

The next byte is the start of another track event, with delta-time set to `0`; it's a *note-on* MIDI-event on channel `0`, note `3C` and velocity of `5A`.

The problem is that in the next event with delta-time set to `01` the event key value is `41` which is neither a midi-event, a sys-event nor a meta-event.

What's happening here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard MIDI files can use [Running Status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_1.0#Message_format) bytes -- the last status byte sent on a channel remains in effect until another status/etc. (and the `5A` that you also show there is the velocity for the second Note On event.)

When sending MIDI data over a cable at 31.25 kb/sec, permitting the system to omit redundant data effectively increases the available bandwidth on the cable.